# General update pattern, on new file upload old doesn't remove

Tags: javascript, d3.js, fileapi

I'am new to d3 so I have problem with general update pattern (I researched all I could find on net).

So, I'm creating web app where I use FileAPI (getAsUrl) for uploading .csv data from PC, that part works fine, but when I upload anything after 1st file all data shows on graph, from all uploaded .csv-s.
Only solution for now is before new upload refreshing browser, but that's not user friendly!

Any help would be much appreciated :)

P.S: if means anything I use Windows, IDE is VScode, graph is scatter plot with regression line.

```
// setting graph, it's not all code for graph
const svg = d3.select(".chart")
   .append("svg")
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
const y = d3.scaleLinear()


//uploading file

//reading in data to chart
function drawChart(url) {         

  //Read the data
   {

    d3.entries(dataset); // pretvara 'object' u 'array'

// Add dots
  var renderChart = (selection, {dataset}) => {
    let dots = selection.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset);
    dots.join (
      enter =>
        enter
              .append("circle")
              .attr("cx", (d) => x(d.x))
              .attr("cy", (d) => y(d.y))
              .attr("r", 4)
              .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
              .attr("opacity", 0.7)
    ),
      update =>
        update
          .attr("cx", (d) => x(d.x))
          .attr("cy", (d) => y(d.y))
          .attr("r", 4)
          .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
          .attr("opacity", 0.7),
        dots
          .exit().remove();

    }
});
}  // that's just scatter plot, there is more code for regression

document.getElementById('file_input').addEventListener('change', getAsUrl, false); 



//in HTML file this is input for button
<input type="file" id="file_input" name="files[]" accept=".csv"  multiple />
```

As I wrote, on first .csv upload everything works fine, but on every next upload old dots stay and new are just added.

Answer (score 2):

Your `join` structure is incorrect. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_join), this is how it should be:

```
selection.join(enter[, update][, exit])
```

As you can see, the `exit` selection is the third argument (the brackets explain that both 2nd and 3rd arguments are optional). More explicitly, still according to the same documentation:

```
.join(
    enter => enter.append("circle"),
    update => update,
    exit => exit.remove()//3rd argument
  )
```

Besides that your *update* part is also incorrect, you can see that it lies outside the `join` method.

That being said, your function should be:

```
dots.join(
  enter => enter.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => x(d.x))
  .attr("cy", (d) => y(d.y))
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
  .attr("opacity", 0.7),
  update => update.attr("cx", (d) => x(d.x))
  .attr("cy", (d) => y(d.y))
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
  .attr("opacity", 0.7),
  exit => exit.exit().remove()
);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, update pattern wasn't like in documentation, but after I change it nothing happened. Stil new data overlaps with old!

Comment: Then you have another problem somewhere else. I suggest you post a new question, with a [mcve].

Comment: Probably it is FileApi what's wrong. But I put in code to show 1st uploaded file dots in one color and on update d3 chart some other color, stil that part isn't showing also. https://jsfiddle.net/gingerM/3Lyxkhbw/